# Visio shapesheet get Layer index from name

Tags: layer, visio, shapesheet

I have some defined shapes in a Visio 2010 stencil, and would like to set the layer depending on the value of a particular shape data field. I would like to do this within the shapesheet if at all possible, since my workplace is very limiting concerning the use of VisualBasic.

I can do the necessary look up to find a particular value, but need to translate this to the correct index in the page layers list.

Basically, I need to get the current index of a particular layer. For example, I know the name of the layer is "Remove" and need the index in ThePage!Layers so that I can set LayerMember accordingly. The index changes from page to page, so I need do this lookup in the context of the page after the shape has been dropped on the page.

How can I look up the index of an entry in ThePage!Layers, using the name of the layer as lookup index. A syntax like ThePage!Layers.Index["Remove"] doesn't work and I couldn't find any other information in the Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible! My method
i add to my shape 3 sections: **User-definded cells**, **Shape Data**, **Layer Membership**.
[image: Add three new sections]
In **Shape Data** section i create one row, which contain Layer Name selector
**User-definded cells** section contain two rows:
1. **User.L_List** store list of all layers on page. I prepare this list use **MS Excel** 
In **column A** i fill row numbers, like as at this picture
[image: Prepare layers list in MS Excel]
In **cell B1** i place formula - **Concatenate("ThePage!Layers.Name";A1)**
In cell B2 i place formula - **Concatenate(B1;"&Listsep()&ThePage!Layers.Name[";A2;"]")**
And pull down some rows as i need. 
Select bottom cell in **column B** and copy that value
Paste this value in **MS Visio's** cell **User.L_List**
2. Next cell contain formula **SETF(GetRef(LayerMember),LOOKUP(Prop.LayerName,User.L_List))**,
which assign shape to layer according value in **Prop.LayerName** cell